# Difference between two relations on the set of real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $R$ be a relation on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $xRy$ iff $|x|< 2 $ $\textbf{and}$ $y = 3$ and $S$ be relation on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $xSy$ iff $|x|< 2 $ $\mathbf{or}$ $y = 3$. Im trying to find domain and range of both relations: I was able to work out the following:

$$ Dom( R) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \exists y \in \mathbb{R} \; \; s.t. \; (x,y) \in R \} = (-2,2) $$

since for every $x \in (-2,2)$ , $y=3$ works. as for the range, I found it is just $y = 3$.

What is difference between these two relations? I am kind of confused with the $or$ and $and$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every pair $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$ is also in $S$, but $S$ contains many pairs that are not in $R$. For instance, $\langle 0,4\rangle\in S$ (because $|0|<2$) and $\langle 6,3\rangle\in S$ (because the second element is $3$); neither statement is true if you replace $S$ with $R$. In order for $\langle x,y\rangle$ to be in $R$, two things have to be true: $|x|<2$, and $y=3$. The pair $\langle x,y\rangle$ is in $S$, however, if at least one of those two things is true. The only pairs $\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ that are *not* in $S$ are the ones in which $|x|\ge 2$ **and** $y\ne 3$, like $\langle 6,4\rangle$.

To get the domain of $S$ suppose that $x$ is any real number; can you find a $y\in\Bbb R$ such that at least one of the following two statements is guaranteed to be true?

- $|x|<2$;
- $y=3$

If the answer is *yes*, you’ve just shown that the domain of $S$ is all of $\Bbb R$. If it isn’t, you’ll have to look a bit closer to see for which $x$ the answer is *yes*.

Then try the same idea to identify the range of $S$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Prof. Scott. My answer for domain and range of $R$ are correct?

Comment: @Willie: You’re welcome. Yes, the domain of $R$ is $(-2,2)$, and the range is $\{3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

@BrianMScott above has already formulated a well thought answer.  Since I already finished making these images, I'll post them anyways as it may help highlight the difference between the two sets.

> Relation $R$ ($|x|<2$ **and** $y=3$)
>   [image: Relation R]

---

> Relation $S$ ($|x|<2$ **or** $y=3$)
>   [image: Relation S]